# Hive - Insert specified values from select statement into table and partition values

Tags: apache, hadoop, hive, hql, partition

I am struggling with inserting only specified values from another table into a partitioned table in Hive as I cannot figure out how to specify the partition columns and the specific columns in the same insert statement. I have read the partition column values need to be the last two in the select statement and in the order they appear in the partition. But the query then complains there are 5 results from the select but only 3 to insert.

Any help would be massively appreciated.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tableName (
code INT,
value1 DECIMAL(12, 8),
value2 DECIMAL(12, 8),
)
PARTITIONED BY(part1 DECIMAL(10, 3), part2 DECIMAL(10, 3));

INSERT INTO TABLE tableName
PARTITION 
(
part1,
part2
) 
(
code,
value1,
value2,
)
SELECT 
code,
value1,
value2,
ROUND(value1, 2),
ROUND(value2, 2) 
FROM importData;
```

Comment: can you post your create schema statement so we can see the destination tbl (tableName).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you have five partitions in two statements `( part1, part2 )` `( code, value1, value2, )`.  You are correct the partitioned columns are stated last.  Perhaps this simplified example will help you get on the right track to accomplish what you're after.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE tblnm PARTITION (p1,p2)
SELECT code, value1, value2, ROUND(value1, 2) as p1, ROUND(value2, 2) as p2
FROM importData;
```

-- **UPDATED** 
May I ask why you have `(code,value1,value2,)` after your partitions?

This should work:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tableName (
code INT,
value1 DECIMAL(12, 8),
value2 DECIMAL(12, 8),
)
PARTITIONED BY(part1 DECIMAL(10, 3), part2 DECIMAL(10, 3));

INSERT INTO TABLE tableName PARTITION (part1,part2) 
  SELECT 
    code,
    value1,
    value2,
    ROUND(value1, 2),
    ROUND(value2, 2) 
  FROM importData;
```

Comment: Hello, I have added the code to create the table into the post, sorry should have included that in the first place.